# Javascript stack trace while running jest test VS stack trace while running an actual app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stack-trace

I am trying to get a stack trace during run time for logging purposes in a React app.

I am doing it by calling:

```
let stackTrace = new Error().stack;
```

When testing with Jest, I got a stack trace like I expected - a trace with file names, method names and line numbers. Example:

> Error
>
> at Object.it (C:\Users\somePath\Logger.test.js:80:19)
>
> at Object.asyncFn (C:\Users\somePath\jasmine-async.js:68:30)
>
> at resolve (C:\Users\somePath\queueRunner.js:38:12)
>
> ...

Based on what I got, I filtered the first line which was always the method which did the logging itself, while I wanted the calling context, and that's why the first line is `Object.it` which is the Jest test.

After that I tried testing it by actually running a react app and sending a message to a backend running on my localhost. The stack trace I got looks different:

> Error
>
> at tryCatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:101275:40)
>
> at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:101509:22)
>
> at Generator.prototype. [as next] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:101327:21)
>
> ...

How can I get a stack trace similar to the one I got on the Jest test, so when someone looks on it, he can view a normal stack trace?

EDIT:

After updating my scripts, I now see a better trace in terms of the name of the method who actually logged the error. It looks like this:

> at onBlur (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:538:82)
>
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:51650:18)

However, is there also a way to get the name of the file where it happened in the original code instead of "http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:538:82"?

Comment: Why are your unit tests pointing to your bundle? How are you running your tests when your app is running?

Comment: Must be a build setting because [for me it works](https://codesandbox.io/s/usedebounce-demo-j4576) (you need to change slider to log). Standard create-react-app works as well. I guess you need to enable source maps in both webpack (if you're not useing create-react-app) and in Chrome (settings -> preferences -> under sources

Comment: @kemicofa the bundle is when I ran a regular react app. the first one is the unit test

Comment: @HMR I did use create react app. I'm not sure what I need to change and where. How do I change it in webpack, and in Chrome, I don't see any preferences or sources inside settings

Comment: If you open the Chrome developer tools (F12) and then press F1 it should open settings. You can check if it's a Chrome problem by opening [this link](https://j4576.codesandbox.io/), change the slider and see what is logged (should not log anything bundle.js).  Maybe check package.json to see what version of react-scripts is installed.

Comment: @HMR I don't see any bundle when using your link. And the source maps were already enabled in Chrome. How do I check it in Firefox? Also, react scripts version is 1.1.5

Comment: If the problem was with Chrome then the link I sent would not work so the problem is with create-react-app. You can try to [update react-scripts](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/) since I'm using version 3.2.0. I would advice you to update in a new git branch in case something breaks. I assume you didn't eject the webpack config because if you did then you can't just update.

Comment: @HMR please check out my edit at the end of the question

Comment: According to the package.json, what version of react-scripts are you on now?

Comment: You can try to remove `node_modules` and remove the lock files (package-lock.json or, if present, npm-shrinkwrap.json for npm and yarn.lock for yarn). Then run npm or yarn install again (provided the package.json has newest version of react-scripts). If that didn't work you can try a new react app `npx create-react-app app-name` and try to see what `console.log(new Error().trace)` will output there.

Comment: @HMR now I'm with version 3.2.0 .